# Saving picture to mysql

Tags: android, mysql, blob

Hey guys I am attempting to save an image in my android applicaiton as a blob in mysql database, as far as the actual code goes. I would love some help as for how to connect to the database in the first place, using the html docs and the actual android code itself.

Comment: What problem you facing?

Comment: I dont know the code in the android program itself and the html docs

Comment: You want to connect Your app to google docs.?

Comment: No I would like to save an image in a mysql database

Comment: I would like to save the image in a mysql database and then be able to retrieve it like a facebook profile picture kind of thing

Comment: do save image into your internal storage and path into the sqlite DB.and retrive it from there.

Comment: I would like the picture to come up every time a user logs in, just like a profile picture in facebook, does this still not require a connection to a database?

Answer (score 2):

Do not save the image itself in DB. Better is it to save the image on your server and only save the path to the image (relative) in DB. Send the needed image to the phone.

Comment: I would like the picture to come up every time a user logs in, just like a profile picture in facebook, does this still not require a connection to a database?

Comment: If you only send the image one time to the phone, the user got only one time data traffic. The other times you have to read only the path out of db. There you need the connection. But you have to look, that the images are not to big and much. Because older smartphones have only small storage pace especially for apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode your image in string using base64. & while accessing from mysql sever decode it again